# Basic Python webscrape script

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, jupyter-notebook

This is my first Python web scraping attempt.

I have an IP camera that saves all of its files to  an HTML document over HTTP. Essentially the camera is its own server that can be accessed over HTTP. The HTML within the server is very basic. It only includes a single body tag, which contains all of it's clips within this body tag. The files look like:

```
MP_2018-04-23_11-14-04_60.mov
```

I am wanting to list/print these files without all of the other HTML associated to it.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urlib.request
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.1.99/form/getStorageFileList').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
body = soup.body
for paragraph in body.find_all('b'):
print(body.text)
```

I've included a few screenshots below as the error I am receiving is very lengthy. I am basically getting:

> attribute error: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'

Would someone clarify and possibly point me in the right direction?

```
usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py in <module>()
     68 
     69 
---> 70 class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
     71 
     72     def __init__(self, soup, namespaceHTMLElements):

AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'
```

[CameraHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVcwa.png)

[Jupyterscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EffCF.png)
[JupyterscriptOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeFot.png)

Comment: Fixed* sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your script.  No big deal though.  Also, you might get more benefit from using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.  What about something like this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

sauce = requests.get('http://192.168.1.99/form/getStorageFileList')
page = sauce.text  #Converted page to text
soup = bs(page,'html.parser')  #Changed to 'html.parser'
body = soup.body('body')  #Added the 'body' tag
for paragraph in body.find_all('b'):
    print(paragraph.text)  #Grabbed the iterated items & converted them to text
```

Let me know if this is something you are looking for.